# In which drawable folders put images with known pixel sizes

Tags: android, image, drawable, android-resources, image-resizing

How correctly put images in appropriate drawable density folders when know their
pixel sizes (like in the list below). I don't understand these dp in Android doc: DisplayMetrics, Supporting Multiple Screens. It seems there is table for drawable density folder - pixel (not dp) size but i can't find it now

```
ecran_accueil_240x320.png

ecran_accueil_320x480.png

ecran_accueil_480x800.png

ecran_accueil_640x920.png

ecran_accueil_640x960.png

ecran_accueil_640x1136.png

ecran_accueil_720x1280.png

ecran_accueil_750x1334.png

ecran_accueil_800x1200.png

ecran_accueil_1080x1920.png
```

Comment: Please refer to the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap has mentioned in the docs. Have a look:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes

Quote from the docs:

> - LDPI: Portrait: 200x320px Landscape: 320x200px
> - MDPI: Portrait:    320x480px Landscape: 480x320px
> - HDPI: Portrait: 480x800px Landscape:    800x480px
> - XHDPI: Portrait: 720px1280px Landscape: 1280x720px
> - XXHDPI:    Portrait: 960px1600px Landscape: 1600x960px
> - XXXHDPI: Portrait:    1280px1920px Landscape: 1920x1280px

Comment: Link always use as a reference. So its better to post as a comment instead of answer !!

Comment: camelCaseCoder, exactly!) THANK YOU!

Comment: @PiyushGupta my bad. Will remember from next time around.

Comment: @KirylIvanou happy to help! :)

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Link only answers are discouraged because links can vanish. To get around that, quote the relevant part of your source in your answer.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Oh ok! I am new around here and still learning. I've made the edit. Thanks. :)

Comment: @camelCaseCoder No worry mate. Mistake can be done by anyone !

Answer (score 1):

> Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes
>   and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a
>   consistent development environment across devices and handles most of
>   the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on
>   which it is displayed. At the same time, the system provides APIs that
>   allow you to control your application's UI for specific screen sizes
>   and densities, in order to optimize your UI design for different
>   screen configurations. For example, you might want a UI for tablets
>   that's different from the UI for handsets.

Please read Official Document And Links .I hope it will helps you .

1. [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
2. [How to support multiple screen in Android](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have always worked :

In your xml file, define the size of your view with the **dp** unit, for example :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="480dp" />
```

and think about the **dp** unit as if it is *millimetre* or *centimetre* ; meaning that no matter where you execute this code, it will always take the same physical size independently from the resolution and the density of the device. In fact, **320 dp = 50.8 mm** and **480 dp = 76.2 mm**.

then, put the images in their drawable folders according to their **pixel** size like this :

- for **ldpi** folder, the rate is **1 dp = 0.75 px** ==> no need to make an image for it (delete its folder)
- in **mdpi** folder, the rate is **1 dp = 1 px**  ==> put the image of ( width=**320px** & height=**480px** )
- in **hdpi** folder, the rate is **1 dp = 1.5 px** ==> put the image of ( width=**480px** & height=**720px**)
- in **xdpi** folder, the rate is **1 dp = 2 px** ==> put the image of ( width=**640px** & height=**960px** )
- in **xxdpi** folder, the rate is **1 dp = 3 px** ==> put the image of ( width=**960px** & height=**1440px** )
- in **xxxdpi** folder, the rate is **1 dp = 4 px** ==> put the image of  (width=**1280px** & height=**1920px** )

These are the perfect sizes that Google strongly recommends in the documentation. However, if you can't provide images that have theses exact pixel sizes, use images that have as close sizes as possible.